# Styling nested Shadow DOMs

Tags: javascript, css, dom, web-component, shadow-dom

Right now, I am trying to style an input in a nested shadow dom in the `vaadin-combo-box`. I use the vaadin web component in a custom web component. At the moment, I can style the `vaadin-text-field` with the following CSS:

```css
vaadin-text-field::part(text-field) { ... }
```

However, I am not able to get into the nested shadow root and style the highlighted div with the `input-field` part.

Is there a solution to that problem or is it not possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For your use case I would use the `themeFor="vaadin-text-field"` inside `@CssImport` and use a theme (and its propagation to sub-components feature, see https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/styling/styling-components/#sub-components) to style it like:

```css
input-field[theme~="my-theme"] { }
```

Not sure if `::part()` is able to go into nested shadow DOM but I would try:

```css
vaadin-text-field::part(text-field)::part(input-field) {}

vaadin-text-field::part(input-field) {}
```